# How to make a request again depending on a variable change in react query?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

I'm trying to make a request again depending on a variable change in react query ?

I'm getting a value from a query parameter in the url , and i'm looking to redo the useQuery if this value changes / exists ,

my useQuery function looks like this :

```
  const { tag } = router.query;

  const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery(["articles"], () =>
    getRecentArticles(tag ? `${tag}` : "")
  );
```

my function looks like this :

```
export const getRecentArticles = async (tag:string) => {
  if (tag.length === 0) {

    const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/articles/?offset=0`)
    return response.data;

  } else {
  const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/articles/?tag=${tag}?offset=0`) 
  return response.data;
}
};
```

but that doesn't really work if my tag variable changes  , Any tips on how to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass it as query key next to articles

```
  const { tag } = router.query;

  const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery(["articles", tag], () =>
    getRecentArticles(tag ? `${tag}` : "")
  );
```

you can read more about query keys in documentation. https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/query-keys

Comment: also small tip: you can use nullish coalescing operator instead ternary 

`getRecentArticles(tag ?? "")`

Comment: yeah that works and it's much cleaner , thanks :)

Comment: even cleaer would be to use default argument in getRecentArticles function :)